# Appcelerator Titanium & Git - what are these random new uncommitted files?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

In my Titanium project, I have been new uncommitted changes to following files being shown in my Git status:

- plugins/ti.alloy/hooks/alloy.js
- plugins/ti.alloy/hooks/deepclean.js

I've never seen or touched those files and someone else in my team got them as well randomly after an update some time ago.

Are these updates to the Titanium Alloy framework that should live in `.gitignore`? Or should I commit them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those files are changed with an update of Alloy (CLI). When you work with multiple people on the same app, it will be recommited every time someone works with a different Alloy version.

You can commit it without causing anything wrong, or you can also add them to gitignore without issues (not tested, but should not cause issues).